# Just by or just?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I'm curious to know whether or not I can use "By" in the following sentences?

Just talking to Him I feel happy.
Just (by) talking to him I feel happy.

Just looking at her I feel proud.
Just (By) looking at her I feel proud.

Just seeing that I want to throw up.
Just (By) seeing that I want to throw up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expressions are very close.

"Just by..." suggests that you are doing something to get that result.

Bare "just..." suggests that you noticed the result without seeking it.

The word "by" doesn't fit well into your example sentences, because they seem apt descriptions of something that happened, not something that one tried to make happen.

Some examples where "just by" would fit better:

*When I want to feel happy, I can do it **just by** talking to him.

If you want to make me sad, you can do it **just by** showing me that video.

If I feel sleepy, I can wake up **just by** drinking a cup of coffee.*

Either with or without "just", the word "by" in this use means that one has done something by a means, "by Xing". The word "just" means that only what follows it was required to have the effect X, whether it was an intended effect or not.